# Compiler error from boost when trying to build debug

Tags: visual-c++, boost, linker, visual-studio-2019

I am getting `include\boost\config\auto_link.hpp(119): fatal error C1189: #error:  "Incompatible build options"` when building my project with debug, but its ok with release.
Is anyone familiar with the issue?